# Touchpad recognized as “PS/2 Generic Mouse” on Dell Inspiron 7506 2-in-1

Tags: 20.04, dell, touchpad, inspiron

I am having trouble to have my touchpad work correctly, on my laptop Dell Inspiron 7506 2n1 with Ubuntu 20.04.

In order to perform a left-click, I need to touch the pad 3 times (instead of 2 usually). I can't perform a right-click by touching the pad with two fingers, nor can I scroll this way.

I noticed that the command `xinput list` returns the following :

```
Virtual core pointer                        id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ CUST0000:00 04F3:2A4B                     id=9    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ PS/2 Generic Mouse                        id=13   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Sleep Button                              id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Integrated_Webcam_HD: Integrate           id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ CUST0000:00 04F3:2A4B                     id=10   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Dell WMI hotkeys                          id=11   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ AT Translated Set 2 keyboard              id=12   [slave  keyboard (3)]
```

Disabling the "PS/2 Generic Mouse" (with `xinput disable 13`) disables the touchpad, so it is id=13. But I can't understand why it is not recognized as a touchpad? Can I do something to have it detected properly?

As asked by @ob2, `sudo journalctl -b` returns the following:

```
-- Logs begin at Tue 2020-11-10 22:46:36 CET, end at Wed 2020-11-11 14:25:20 CE>
nov. 11 10:22:48 MACHINE kernel: Linux version 5.4.0-52-generic (buildd@lgw01-a>
nov. 11 10:22:48 MACHINE kernel: Command line: BOOT_IMAGE=/vmlinuz-5.4.0-52-gen>
nov. 11 10:22:48 MACHINE kernel: KERNEL supported cpus:
nov. 11 10:22:48 MACHINE kernel:   Intel GenuineIntel
nov. 11 10:22:48 MACHINE kernel:   AMD AuthenticAMD
nov. 11 10:22:48 MACHINE kernel:   Hygon HygonGenuine
nov. 11 10:22:48 MACHINE kernel:   Centaur CentaurHauls
nov. 11 10:22:48 MACHINE kernel:   zhaoxin   Shanghai  
nov. 11 10:22:48 MACHINE kernel: x86/fpu: Supporting XSAVE feature 0x001: 'x87 >
nov. 11 10:22:48 MACHINE kernel: x86/fpu: Supporting XSAVE feature 0x002: 'SSE >
nov. 11 10:22:48 MACHINE kernel: x86/fpu: Supporting XSAVE feature 0x004: 'AVX >
nov. 11 10:22:48 MACHINE kernel: x86/fpu: Supporting XSAVE feature 0x020: 'AVX->
nov. 11 10:22:48 MACHINE kernel: x86/fpu: Supporting XSAVE feature 0x040: 'AVX->
nov. 11 10:22:48 MACHINE kernel: x86/fpu: Supporting XSAVE feature 0x080: 'AVX->
nov. 11 10:22:48 MACHINE kernel: x86/fpu: Supporting XSAVE feature 0x200: 'Prot>
nov. 11 10:22:48 MACHINE kernel: x86/fpu: xstate_offset[2]:  576, xstate_sizes[>
nov. 11 10:22:48 MACHINE kernel: x86/fpu: xstate_offset[5]:  832, xstate_sizes[>
nov. 11 10:22:48 MACHINE kernel: x86/fpu: xstate_offset[6]:  896, xstate_sizes[>
nov. 11 10:22:48 MACHINE kernel: x86/fpu: xstate_offset[7]: 1408, xstate_sizes[>
nov. 11 10:22:48 MACHINE kernel: x86/fpu: xstate_offset[9]: 2432, xstate_sizes[>
nov. 11 10:22:48 MACHINE kernel: x86/fpu: Enabled xstate features 0x2e7, contex>
nov. 11 10:22:48 MACHINE kernel: BIOS-provided physical RAM map:
lines 1-23...skipping...
-- Logs begin at Tue 2020-11-10 22:46:36 CET, end at Wed 2020-11-11 14:25:20 CET. --
nov. 11 10:22:48 MACHINE kernel: Linux version 5.4.0-52-generic (buildd@lgw01-amd64-060) (gcc version 9.3.0 (Ubuntu 9.3.0-17ubuntu1~20.04)) #57-Ubuntu SMP Thu Oct 15 10:57:00 UTC 2020 (Ubuntu 5.4.0-52.57-generic>
nov. 11 10:22:48 MACHINE kernel: Command line: BOOT_IMAGE=/vmlinuz-5.4.0-52-generic root=/dev/mapper/vgubuntu-root ro quiet splash acpi_backlight=vendor vt.handoff=7
nov. 11 10:22:48 MACHINE kernel: KERNEL supported cpus:
nov. 11 10:22:48 MACHINE kernel:   Intel GenuineIntel
nov. 11 10:22:48 MACHINE kernel:   AMD AuthenticAMD
nov. 11 10:22:48 MACHINE kernel:   Hygon HygonGenuine
nov. 11 10:22:48 MACHINE kernel:   Centaur CentaurHauls
nov. 11 10:22:48 MACHINE kernel:   zhaoxin   Shanghai  
nov. 11 10:22:48 MACHINE kernel: x86/fpu: Supporting XSAVE feature 0x001: 'x87 floating point registers'
nov. 11 10:22:48 MACHINE kernel: x86/fpu: Supporting XSAVE feature 0x002: 'SSE registers'
nov. 11 10:22:48 MACHINE kernel: x86/fpu: Supporting XSAVE feature 0x004: 'AVX registers'
nov. 11 10:22:48 MACHINE kernel: x86/fpu: Supporting XSAVE feature 0x020: 'AVX-512 opmask'
nov. 11 10:22:48 MACHINE kernel: x86/fpu: Supporting XSAVE feature 0x040: 'AVX-512 Hi256'
nov. 11 10:22:48 MACHINE kernel: x86/fpu: Supporting XSAVE feature 0x080: 'AVX-512 ZMM_Hi256'
nov. 11 10:22:48 MACHINE kernel: x86/fpu: Supporting XSAVE feature 0x200: 'Protection Keys User registers'
nov. 11 10:22:48 MACHINE kernel: x86/fpu: xstate_offset[2]:  576, xstate_sizes[2]:  256
nov. 11 10:22:48 MACHINE kernel: x86/fpu: xstate_offset[5]:  832, xstate_sizes[5]:   64
nov. 11 10:22:48 MACHINE kernel: x86/fpu: xstate_offset[6]:  896, xstate_sizes[6]:  512
nov. 11 10:22:48 MACHINE kernel: x86/fpu: xstate_offset[7]: 1408, xstate_sizes[7]: 1024
nov. 11 10:22:48 MACHINE kernel: x86/fpu: xstate_offset[9]: 2432, xstate_sizes[9]:    8
nov. 11 10:22:48 MACHINE kernel: x86/fpu: Enabled xstate features 0x2e7, context size is 2440 bytes, using 'compacted' format.
nov. 11 10:22:48 MACHINE kernel: BIOS-provided physical RAM map:
nov. 11 10:22:48 MACHINE kernel: BIOS-e820: [mem 0x0000000000000000-0x000000000009efff] usable
nov. 11 10:22:48 MACHINE kernel: BIOS-e820: [mem 0x000000000009f000-0x00000000000fffff] reserved
nov. 11 10:22:48 MACHINE kernel: BIOS-e820: [mem 0x0000000000100000-0x000000005f32afff] usable
nov. 11 10:22:48 MACHINE kernel: BIOS-e820: [mem 0x000000005f32b000-0x0000000063110fff] reserved
nov. 11 10:22:48 MACHINE kernel: BIOS-e820: [mem 0x0000000063111000-0x0000000063971fff] ACPI NVS
nov. 11 10:22:48 MACHINE kernel: BIOS-e820: [mem 0x0000000063972000-0x0000000063bfefff] ACPI data
nov. 11 10:22:48 MACHINE kernel: BIOS-e820: [mem 0x0000000063bff000-0x0000000063bfffff] usable
nov. 11 10:22:48 MACHINE kernel: BIOS-e820: [mem 0x0000000063c00000-0x0000000067ffffff] reserved
nov. 11 10:22:48 MACHINE kernel: BIOS-e820: [mem 0x0000000068600000-0x00000000687fffff] reserved
nov. 11 10:22:48 MACHINE kernel: BIOS-e820: [mem 0x0000000069000000-0x00000000707fffff] reserved
nov. 11 10:22:48 MACHINE kernel: BIOS-e820: [mem 0x00000000c0000000-0x00000000cfffffff] reserved
nov. 11 10:22:48 MACHINE kernel: BIOS-e820: [mem 0x00000000fed20000-0x00000000fed7ffff] reserved
nov. 11 10:22:48 MACHINE kernel: BIOS-e820: [mem 0x00000000ff000000-0x00000000ffffffff] reserved
nov. 11 10:22:48 MACHINE kernel: BIOS-e820: [mem 0x0000000100000000-0x000000048f7fffff] usable
nov. 11 10:22:48 MACHINE kernel: NX (Execute Disable) protection: active
nov. 11 10:22:48 MACHINE kernel: efi: EFI v2.70 by Dell
nov. 11 10:22:48 MACHINE kernel: efi:  ACPI=0x63bfe000  ACPI 2.0=0x63bfe014  TPMFinalLog=0x63917000  SMBIOS=0x5f9e3000  ESRT=0x5f991e98  MEMATTR=0x5aa85418  TPMEventLog=0x5a96f018 
nov. 11 10:22:48 MACHINE kernel: secureboot: Secure boot enabled
nov. 11 10:22:48 MACHINE kernel: Kernel is locked down from EFI Secure Boot mode; see man kernel_lockdown.7
nov. 11 10:22:48 MACHINE kernel: SMBIOS 3.2 present.
nov. 11 10:22:48 MACHINE kernel: DMI: Dell Inc. Inspiron 7506 2n1/04NTGP, BIOS 1.1.6 10/27/2020
nov. 11 10:22:48 MACHINE kernel: tsc: Detected 2800.000 MHz processor
nov. 11 10:22:48 MACHINE kernel: tsc: Detected 2803.200 MHz TSC
nov. 11 10:22:48 MACHINE kernel: e820: update [mem 0x00000000-0x00000fff] usable ==> reserved
nov. 11 10:22:48 MACHINE kernel: e820: remove [mem 0x000a0000-0x000fffff] usable
nov. 11 10:22:48 MACHINE kernel: last_pfn = 0x48f800 max_arch_pfn = 0x400000000
nov. 11 10:22:48 MACHINE kernel: MTRR default type: write-back
nov. 11 10:22:48 MACHINE kernel: MTRR fixed ranges enabled:
nov. 11 10:22:48 MACHINE kernel:   00000-9FFFF write-back
nov. 11 10:22:48 MACHINE kernel:   A0000-BFFFF uncachable
nov. 11 10:22:48 MACHINE kernel:   C0000-FFFFF write-protect
nov. 11 10:22:48 MACHINE kernel: MTRR variable ranges enabled:
nov. 11 10:22:48 MACHINE kernel:   0 base 0080000000 mask 7F80000000 uncachable
nov. 11 10:22:48 MACHINE kernel:   1 base 0070000000 mask 7FF0000000 uncachable
nov. 11 10:22:48 MACHINE kernel:   2 base 006C000000 mask 7FFC000000 uncachable
lines 1-58
























































-- Logs begin at Tue 2020-11-10 22:46:36 CET, end at Wed 2020-11-11 14:25:20 CET. --
nov. 11 10:22:48 MACHINE kernel: Linux version 5.4.0-52-generic (buildd@lgw01-amd64-060) (gcc version 9.3.0 (Ubuntu 9.3.0-17ubuntu1~20.04)) #57-Ubuntu SMP Thu Oct 15 10:57:00 UTC 2020 (Ubuntu 5.4.0-52.57-g>
nov. 11 10:22:48 MACHINE kernel: Command line: BOOT_IMAGE=/vmlinuz-5.4.0-52-generic root=/dev/mapper/vgubuntu-root ro quiet splash acpi_backlight=vendor vt.handoff=7
nov. 11 10:22:48 MACHINE kernel: KERNEL supported cpus:
nov. 11 10:22:48 MACHINE kernel:   Intel GenuineIntel
nov. 11 10:22:48 MACHINE kernel:   AMD AuthenticAMD
nov. 11 10:22:48 MACHINE kernel:   Hygon HygonGenuine
nov. 11 10:22:48 MACHINE kernel:   Centaur CentaurHauls
nov. 11 10:22:48 MACHINE kernel:   zhaoxin   Shanghai  
nov. 11 10:22:48 MACHINE kernel: x86/fpu: Supporting XSAVE feature 0x001: 'x87 floating point registers'
nov. 11 10:22:48 MACHINE kernel: x86/fpu: Supporting XSAVE feature 0x002: 'SSE registers'
nov. 11 10:22:48 MACHINE kernel: x86/fpu: Supporting XSAVE feature 0x004: 'AVX registers'
nov. 11 10:22:48 MACHINE kernel: x86/fpu: Supporting XSAVE feature 0x020: 'AVX-512 opmask'
nov. 11 10:22:48 MACHINE kernel: x86/fpu: Supporting XSAVE feature 0x040: 'AVX-512 Hi256'
nov. 11 10:22:48 MACHINE kernel: x86/fpu: Supporting XSAVE feature 0x080: 'AVX-512 ZMM_Hi256'
nov. 11 10:22:48 MACHINE kernel: x86/fpu: Supporting XSAVE feature 0x200: 'Protection Keys User registers'
nov. 11 10:22:48 MACHINE kernel: x86/fpu: xstate_offset[2]:  576, xstate_sizes[2]:  256
nov. 11 10:22:48 MACHINE kernel: x86/fpu: xstate_offset[5]:  832, xstate_sizes[5]:   64
nov. 11 10:22:48 MACHINE kernel: x86/fpu: xstate_offset[6]:  896, xstate_sizes[6]:  512
nov. 11 10:22:48 MACHINE kernel: x86/fpu: xstate_offset[7]: 1408, xstate_sizes[7]: 1024
nov. 11 10:22:48 MACHINE kernel: x86/fpu: xstate_offset[9]: 2432, xstate_sizes[9]:    8
nov. 11 10:22:48 MACHINE kernel: x86/fpu: Enabled xstate features 0x2e7, context size is 2440 bytes, using 'compacted' format.
nov. 11 10:22:48 MACHINE kernel: BIOS-provided physical RAM map:
nov. 11 10:22:48 MACHINE kernel: BIOS-e820: [mem 0x0000000000000000-0x000000000009efff] usable
nov. 11 10:22:48 MACHINE kernel: BIOS-e820: [mem 0x000000000009f000-0x00000000000fffff] reserved
nov. 11 10:22:48 MACHINE kernel: BIOS-e820: [mem 0x0000000000100000-0x000000005f32afff] usable
nov. 11 10:22:48 MACHINE kernel: BIOS-e820: [mem 0x000000005f32b000-0x0000000063110fff] reserved
nov. 11 10:22:48 MACHINE kernel: BIOS-e820: [mem 0x0000000063111000-0x0000000063971fff] ACPI NVS
nov. 11 10:22:48 MACHINE kernel: BIOS-e820: [mem 0x0000000063972000-0x0000000063bfefff] ACPI data
nov. 11 10:22:48 MACHINE kernel: BIOS-e820: [mem 0x0000000063bff000-0x0000000063bfffff] usable
nov. 11 10:22:48 MACHINE kernel: BIOS-e820: [mem 0x0000000063c00000-0x0000000067ffffff] reserved
nov. 11 10:22:48 MACHINE kernel: BIOS-e820: [mem 0x0000000068600000-0x00000000687fffff] reserved
nov. 11 10:22:48 MACHINE kernel: BIOS-e820: [mem 0x0000000069000000-0x00000000707fffff] reserved
nov. 11 10:22:48 MACHINE kernel: BIOS-e820: [mem 0x00000000c0000000-0x00000000cfffffff] reserved
nov. 11 10:22:48 MACHINE kernel: BIOS-e820: [mem 0x00000000fed20000-0x00000000fed7ffff] reserved
nov. 11 10:22:48 MACHINE kernel: BIOS-e820: [mem 0x00000000ff000000-0x00000000ffffffff] reserved
nov. 11 10:22:48 MACHINE kernel: BIOS-e820: [mem 0x0000000100000000-0x000000048f7fffff] usable
nov. 11 10:22:48 MACHINE kernel: NX (Execute Disable) protection: active
nov. 11 10:22:48 MACHINE kernel: efi: EFI v2.70 by Dell
nov. 11 10:22:48 MACHINE kernel: efi:  ACPI=0x63bfe000  ACPI 2.0=0x63bfe014  TPMFinalLog=0x63917000  SMBIOS=0x5f9e3000  ESRT=0x5f991e98  MEMATTR=0x5aa85418  TPMEventLog=0x5a96f018 
nov. 11 10:22:48 MACHINE kernel: secureboot: Secure boot enabled
nov. 11 10:22:48 MACHINE kernel: Kernel is locked down from EFI Secure Boot mode; see man kernel_lockdown.7
nov. 11 10:22:48 MACHINE kernel: SMBIOS 3.2 present.
nov. 11 10:22:48 MACHINE kernel: DMI: Dell Inc. Inspiron 7506 2n1/04NTGP, BIOS 1.1.6 10/27/2020
nov. 11 10:22:48 MACHINE kernel: tsc: Detected 2800.000 MHz processor
nov. 11 10:22:48 MACHINE kernel: tsc: Detected 2803.200 MHz TSC
nov. 11 10:22:48 MACHINE kernel: e820: update [mem 0x00000000-0x00000fff] usable ==> reserved
nov. 11 10:22:48 MACHINE kernel: e820: remove [mem 0x000a0000-0x000fffff] usable
nov. 11 10:22:48 MACHINE kernel: last_pfn = 0x48f800 max_arch_pfn = 0x400000000
nov. 11 10:22:48 MACHINE kernel: MTRR default type: write-back
nov. 11 10:22:48 MACHINE kernel: MTRR fixed ranges enabled:
nov. 11 10:22:48 MACHINE kernel:   00000-9FFFF write-back
nov. 11 10:22:48 MACHINE kernel:   A0000-BFFFF uncachable
nov. 11 10:22:48 MACHINE kernel:   C0000-FFFFF write-protect
nov. 11 10:22:48 MACHINE kernel: MTRR variable ranges enabled:
lines 1-55
```

Answer (score 0):

Most ToughPad on laptop has two ways to be detected :

- As I2C mouse, with multi touch capabilities.
- As PS/2 mouse, used whenever I2C drivers are not available (e.g. during Windows setup).

If your mouse is detected as PS/2, that's probably mean that your I2C drivers is missing or mouse is enable as PS/2 by default by the kernel. Here a small process to try to fix that.

It's now difficult to find the correct process (if feasible), but you may first check your kernel logs with the following command and look for Mouse entries.

```
sudo journalctl -b
```

Make search of "input" by typing `/input` and check for input detected. Eventually put some logs here.

You can have a look on this page (this is for Debian, but most processes works for Ubuntu as well).

```
https://wiki.debian.org/SynapticsTouchpad
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply! I added the return from ```sudo journalctl -b```. But I can't see anything containing the words "input" nor "mouse"...

Comment: Can you copy/paste the content somewhere ?

Comment: I put it in my first post.